# Can I re-order my issues in Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

I’m using Bitbucket’s issues feature to track bugs and enhancements on a project I’m working on.

By default, it seems to sort the list of issues by last updated, or similar. This is a bit annoying when I want to quickly note down an issue, but deal with it after a few other more pressing issues, or put e.g. three issues in order of priority.

Can I order the list arbitrarily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking the “Bump!” button at the bottom of each issue puts that issue to the top of the default sort order.

Comment: I would say that this is not very practical if you have a lot of issues, because you have to do it a particular order and if you'll miss something then you will have to _bump_ again..!

Comment: @Lipis: yah, I know. That’s why I asked the question in the first place. Unfortunately, there don’t seem to be any other options.

Comment: @Paul I still think its better to organize your issues in categories/versions so you can easily order them by version number for example.

Comment: @Lipis: oh sure, that definitely helps. But you’re still going to have multiple issues in each milestone/version, which you can’t re-order arbitrarily (as far as I can tell) except via “bump”. And also (again, as far as I can tell), you can’t re-order milestones/versions arbitrarily, so you have to be careful with your version/milestone names to allow inserting one halfway down your list.

Comment: @Paul all that if the order of the issues is that important.. better idea is to close the issues and have that list empty.. hehe :) gl on whatever you'll do...

Comment: @Lipis: now *there’s* a solution I hadn’t thought of :)

Answer (score 5):

From **Admin** > **Issue tracker settings** of your project you are able to add **Components**, **Versions** and **Milestones**. Once you'll add them then you will be able to sort them by these options and can create as many as you wish.